# How to redirect the user according to their user groups in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I have created my website in Joomla. In my site I have created 3 user groups ('guest', 'unregistered', 'registered'), and I have created one blog kind of thing called abstract corner in article. The 'guest' and 'unregistered' user can just view the guidelines but they can't submit the abstracts. The 'registered' user can submit abstracts. I am using two images to display "abstract guidelines" and an "abstract submission" link. How can I redirect this user to particular article?

Please help me. I am new to Joomla .

Comment: Can you further clarify the meaning of your key question, "How can I redirect this user to particular article?" It is not clear what you are asking. Do you want to know how to attach links from the images to those pages?

Comment: ya i want to attach link from the images to those page using 2 conditions . condition 1 ->if that user is is a registered user then he can access submission page . condition 2 -> if he is not a registered user then he need to redirect to other page .for the same image link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution :

```
1.first you need to find out user group id

$user = JFactory::getUser();
$groups = $user->get('groups');

  foreach($groups as $group) {
 if ($group==3)//ex: group id is 3 for registered user 

 {

    echo"redirect page 1";

  }else{

   echo "redirect page 2";

     }


   }
```